# How enter to mysql from the console of Ubuntu?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, mysql

I have an user called root  and his password is "12233" in localhost

How I enter to mysql from the Ubuntu's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql -u root -p

And after it will ask you your password just type it in and that's it.

Comment: $ mysql -u root -p12233

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password] [dbname]
```

for example:

```
mysql -u myuserid -p mypassword mainDB
```

This will give you access into `mysql` and then you can run different commands within the MySQL shell, like:

```
 use mainDB --->select the DB you want to work on
 select * from tablename; ---> get all records form the table table name
```

Hope this helps.